# Running User for Apex class invocable methods called from Process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, invocable-method

I am calling a invocable method from a Process builder, the running user is myself(System Admin), however the invocable method is running under "Automated Process" user?
Is this the expected behaviour of Salesforce?

Comment: Does the process builder subscribe to Platform Events?

Comment: No, it's running on update custom object.